# trying to delay part of my program

Tags: python, screenshot, delay

Im trying to take a snapshot of the webpage i open but i need to delay the second part of the code so that the program has time to open the page

Here is the code

```
import os
import sys
import time
import Image
import ImageGrab


import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new(input("URL: "))
#Need to delay here

SaveDirectory=r'C:\Documents and Settings\User\My Documents\My Pictures'
ImageEditorPath=r'C:\WINDOWS\system32\mspaint.exe'
img=ImageGrab.grab()
box = (100, 100, 400, 400)
region = img.crop(box)
saveas=os.path.join(SaveDirectory,'ScreenShot_'+'.png')
img.save(saveas)
editorstring='""%s" "%s"'% (ImageEditorPath,saveas) 
os.system(editorstring)
```

Comment: try selenium webdriver for a much more robust method of capturing screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use time.sleep(seconds) to let your program delay for a while.

Answer (score 2):

taking a screenshot with [selenium webdriver bindings for python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.google.com/')
browser.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
browser.quit()
```